# PHP rank system with mysql

Tags: php

I need to make a ranking system in php with a database.
Here an example:

```
<?php
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_accounts ORDER BY Level DESC");
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if( !$result ){
  echo 'SQL Query Failed';
}else{
  $rank = 0;
  $last_score = false;
  $rows = 0;
  while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ){
    $rows++;
    if( $last_score!= $row['Level'] ){
      $last_score = $row['Level'];
      $rank = $rows;
    }
    echo "rank ".$rank." is ".$row['name']." with point ".$row['Level']."";
  }
}
?>
```

my problem is that doesn t work help?

Comment: What kind of help do you need?

Comment: what data do you have? what information is on each variable? how do you want to rank that?. Please give all the related information plus tell us what have you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't make any sense:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_accounts ORDER BY Level DESC");
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Your first point of call would be to fix this up (I'm assuming it should just be the query as a string on the first line and the query **call** on the second. You'll also want to add some debugging options like `mysql_error()` to find out when/if it fails:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_accounts ORDER BY Level DESC";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

And switch to `mysqli` or `PDO` soon as `mysql_*` lib is deprecated.